# Why we should use Equatable in Flutter Bloc?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I understand that Equatable helps to compare two instances of object without doing it manually.
But where exactly I can use it in Flutter Bloc?

Here is the example of usage Equatable:
Where it could be useful?

```
abstract class TodosState extends Equatable {
  const TodosState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class TodosLoadInProgress extends TodosState {}

class TodosLoadSuccess extends TodosState {
  final List<Todo> todos;

  const TodosLoadSuccess([this.todos = const []]);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [todos];

  @override
  String toString() => 'TodosLoadSuccess { todos: $todos }';
}

class TodosLoadFailure extends TodosState {}
```

Comment: Maybe here is the answer for you: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/faqs?id=when-to-use-equatable

Answer (score 3):

Object and data comparison is always hard to do when it comes to stream as we need to decide state updation based on it.
we required `Equatable` as it overrides `==` and `hashCode` internally, which saves a lot of boilerplate code. In `Bloc`, we have to extend `Equatable` to `States and Events` classes to use this functionality.

```
 abstract class TodosState extends Equatable {}
```

So, that means `TodosState` will not make duplicate calls and will not going to rebuild the widget if the same state occurs.

Let's see `props` usage in Equatable and what makes it special

**Define State without props:**

```
  class TodosLoadSuccess extends TodosState {}
```

**Define State with props:**

`props` declared when we want `State` to be compared against the values which declared inside props List

```
class TodosLoadSuccess extends TodosState {
  final String name;
  final List<Todo> todos;
  const TodosLoadSuccess([this.name, this.todos = const []]);

   @override
   List<Object> get props => [name, todos];

 }
```

If we remove the name from the list and keep a list like `[this.todos]`, then `State` will only consider the `todos` field, avoiding the `name` field. That is why we used props for handling State changes.

**Bloc Stream Usage:**

As we extending `State with Equatable` that makes a comparison of old state data with new state data. For example, let's look at the below example here TodosState will build a widget only once, which will avoid the second call as it is duplicated.

```
@override
Stream<TodosState> mapEventToState(MyEvent event) async* {
  final List<Todo> todos = [Todo(), Todo()];
  yield TodosLoadSuccess(todos);
  yield TodosLoadSuccess(todos); // This will be avoided
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think it is useful for comparing what state is in BlocBuilder.
Below code is a good example of using Equatable.

```
if(state is [Some State])
```

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return BlocBuilder<SongsSearchBloc, SongsSearchState>
    bloc: BlocProvider.of(context),
    builder: (BuildContext context, SongsSearchState state) {
      if (state is SearchStateLoading) {
        return  CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
      if (state is SearchStateError) {
        return Text(state.error);
      }
      if (state is SearchStateSuccess) {
        return state.songs.isEmpty
            ? Text(S.EMPTY_LIST.tr())
            : Expanded(
                child: _SongsSearchResults(
                  songsList: state.songs,
                ),
              );
      } else {
        return  Text(S.ENTER_SONG_TITLE.tr());
      }
    },
  );
}
```